# mysql second priority where clause

Tags: php, mysql

So for example I have a table users, with a column 'count' and a column 'uid' which is the primary key.

```
uid | count
1   |  20
2   |  20
3   |  20
4   |  20
4   |  18
```

I want to select exactly one row which has count less than or equal to the present row. For example, I have the row where uid = 2.

Now I want to select a column which has count less than or equal to the present count value which is "20". and I want to select exactly one row which is closest to it.

Now I will have the choice to select either the row which has uid = 3 or uid = 4. In such case, I will want to select the column with the lowest uid value such that it is greater than the present uid value which is 2. Therefore I will want uid = 3 as my result.

How to put this in a mysql query ?

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE count <= 20
ORDER BY count DESC, uid ASC
LIMIT 1
```

That'll sort the results so that everything above 20 is discarded, and you get the rest in decreasing count order, with lower user ids taking priority if there are multiples of the same count. The `LIMIT 1` restricts the query to return only one row.

If you want to make the comparison to an existing row, your easiest bet is to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE count <= 20
  AND uid != 2
ORDER BY count DESC, uid ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanx....I will need to add one more line to that...

`where count <=20 AND uid > 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE count <= 20
  AND uid IN (3,4)
ORDER BY  uid ASC,count DESC
LIMIT 1
```